# While Loop / algorithm issues c++ visual studio 2012

Tags: c++

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>         //for cin >> and cout <<
#include <cassert>          //for assert
#include <iomanip>          //for endl
#include <chrono>

using std::chrono::system_clock;
using namespace std;

//declare constants: symbols used for the drawing

const char EOL('\n');       //end of line symbol
const char BLANK(' ');
const char LEAF('#');

//declare global variables
int treeHeight;             //height of the tree
int branchLine;             //loop counter for each line of the foliage
int counter;



void getValidHeigth()       //get valid height for the tree
{
    cout << "\nPlease enter a height for the tree: ";
    cin >> treeHeight;
    if ((treeHeight < 4) | (treeHeight >20))
    while ((treeHeight < 4) | (treeHeight > 20))
    {
        cout << "\nERROR: Invalid height! Please enter a height for the tree (4-20): ";
        cin >> treeHeight;
    }
}

void drawABranch()          
{
    int spaces(1); 
    counter = 3;
    int foliage (0);

        while (spaces <= (treeHeight - counter)) 
        {
        cout << (BLANK);
        spaces ++;
        }
        while (foliage < branchLine)
        {
            cout << LEAF;
            foliage ++;

        }
}

void drawBranches()     

    for (branchLine = 1; branchLine <= (treeHeight - 2); ++branchLine)
    {
        drawABranch();  
        cout << EOL;    
    }
    branchLine++;

}

void drawTrunk()
{           
    int trunkLine, spaces;
    const char WOOD('|');
    trunkLine = 1;
    while (trunkLine <= 2) 
    {
        spaces = 1;
        while (spaces <= (treeHeight - 3)) 
        {
        cout << (BLANK);
        spaces ++;
        }
    cout << (WOOD);
    cout << (EOL);
    trunkLine ++; 
    }
}


int main()                  
{


    time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
    struct tm * now = localtime(&t);

    switch ((now->tm_mon + 1)) {
    case 1:
        cout << now->tm_mday << " January " << (now->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << now->tm_mday << " February " << (now->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << now->tm_mday << " March " << (now->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << now->tm_mday << " April " << (now->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << now->tm_mday << " May " << (now->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
        break;
    case 6:
        cout << now->tm_mday << " June " << (now->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
        break;
    case 7:
        cout << now->tm_mday << " July " << (now->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
        break;
    case 8:
        cout << now->tm_mday << " August " << (now->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
        break;
    case 9:
        cout << now->tm_mday << "  September  " << (now->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
        break;
    case 10:
        cout << now->tm_mday << " October " << (now->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
        break;
    case 11:
        cout << now->tm_mday << " November " << (now->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
        break;
    case 12:
        cout << now->tm_mday << " December " << (now->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
        break;
    }

    getValidHeigth();

    cout << EOL;
    drawBranches();
    drawTrunk();
    cout << EOL;
    system("PAUSE");        //hold the screen until a key is pressed
    return(0);
}
```

Hi,
This is my code of my current program. I'm having trouble with the drawABranch and drawBranches procedures. Currently if I run the program it draws half the christmas tree correctly. However I there is a problem with the first while loop of my spaces I believe.

```
> this is what it does: 
>       #
>       ##
>       ###
>       ####
>       |
>       |  instead of:
>       #
>      ###
>     ##### 
     #######
>       |
>       |
```

Could anyone possibly show me in the right direction of where my error is, and possibly how to overcome this?

Thank you

Comment: Um, why did you include the part that prints the date? That seems to be unrelated to the problem. You even knew that because you didn't include it in your sample output.

Comment: Why the big switch. Just bung it into an  array and index on that

Comment: I had to write the output, because I can't attach pictures. The date is meant to be there, don't worry! @Ed, I'm not sure how to do that, and I understand what I've done with the switch.

Comment: @user2950449 - Get an array and index into that. Why Should I worry

Answer (score 0):

The main problem (except that you are missing an opening curly brace after drawABranch() and thus it didn't compile here) is, that this line:

```
while (spaces <= (treeHeight - counter))
```

is constant in branchLine (i.e. the right side of <= is always treeHeight - 3, however this value should depend on branchLine as this is your index for the currently printed tree height. I fixed your code, however I'm not gonna paste the entirely corrected code (there are some other problems with it), but as a hint, consider this line in my version:

```
int spacesNeeded = SPACE_LEFT_OF_TREE + (treeHeight-2-(branchLine-1));
```

Btw: I have no idea what your "counter" variable means. Before asking a question on SO, please sanitize your code with respect to length (your main() really is not necessary here) and in terms of expressiveness of variable names (actually, you should always do that).

My line above should give you a hint, however as mentioned expect some other minor problems to occur.

Edit: I forgot to mention the reason why I won't paste my code which is the fact, that this looks a lot like an exercise a teacher might force you to do ;)

Comment: Thank you, I haven't asked for you to post your code; otherwise I won't be able to learn myself. I asked for help for solving the issue, which I am going to do with the help you just provided! The counter variable is excess from an edit to the code I did earlier trying to fix the problem. It's not used in the code at the moment but was in a previous version. I forgot to take it out.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that `if ((treeHeight < 4) | (treeHeight >20))` and `while ((treeHeight < 4) | (treeHeight > 20))` should be `if ((treeHeight < 4) || (treeHeight > 20))` and `while ((treeHeight < 4) || (treeHeight > 20))` respectively (notice the `||` instead of `|`).